# how to share my computer using ftp,i need to access it from anywhere assuming static ip?

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I need to access my PC using ftp , how to do that?
there is FILE Z  but i can't configure it right
any ideas , not necessarily FILE Z
I tried shiftedit but i have no clue what is that
windows7 basic home

Comment: you can you use team viewer to do such things.

Comment: actually vnc and chrome remote desktop do this easily, but i wanna explore the HDD without controling the pc

Answer (score 1):

I would forget FTP and think about using SCP/SSH. It's secure, as easy to install as FTP, or even more depending on the software you choose, and you can find a lot of reliable tools: WinSCP, Putty, OpenSSH, etc...

As your need is related to file transfer, you could combine:

1 - http://mobassh.mobatek.net/ as the server
2 - https://winscp.net/eng/download.php as the client.

They both combine well:
http://mobassh.mobatek.net/documentation.html#4

WinSCP has a straight installation procedure, it is just a client, you'll only need to configure your connections like in any other FTP client. In fact WinSCP also supports plain FTP.

In regards to the SSH server, follow the creator instructions here:
http://mobassh.mobatek.net/documentation.html#1a

Comment: the thing is i have an app on android support ftp,sftp,ftps and webdav beside lan

Comment: @dimmu WHAT?  what do you mean by an app on android support and what has that got to do with your accessing your computer. And by the way, ftp and ftps are secure. Just plain ftp isn't.

Comment: its an app called es file explorer, i like using it to access my pc using lan,,,,the app also has ftp client settings,i wanna set up an ftp server on my pc and access it from my phone using that app through data connection network

Comment: Well, you have two to three mixed questions here which need to be treated independently: 
1/ setup an FTP server, 
2/ Open-forward TCP ports 20 and 21 from your public IP to your LAN IP (in case you are NATed). If you are on a mobile connection (the server) or for any other reason have a public IP, you can skip NAT config. 3/ In any case you'll also need a dynamic DNS tool if you don't have a fixed IP. This is not rocket science, but you need to dissect & comprehend every individual concept involved, otherwise any success in doing what you want will be a matter of luck.